# After Win10 2004 update, Outlook 2016 forgets POP passwords each time I restart the application and/or windows

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, windows-update, credentials-manager

Since applying the 2004 update (May 2020) to Windows 10 Pro, my Outlook 2016 has been "forgetting" the saved POP passwords on every restart of Outlook. Chrome also showing similar issue, by not remembering profile passwords between restarts.

I have tried a number of suggested fixes I found on the web, but so far nothing has helped.

From the 4 machines I have access to, this has happened on 2 and I cannot understand what is going wrong. Many others are complaining about this.

I login with local account and not a Microsoft account.

Can anyone help? This is driving me mad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching online again and trying a number of new suggestions, I finally found a hint that worked for me.

My Windows accounts were setup as Local Accounts. When I changed them to "**Sign in with Microsoft account instead**" in the "Your Info" settings page, the problem went away and I could once again restart the applications (Outlook 2016 and Chrome browser), shut the computer down, and reboot the computers and the saved passwords were remembered.

After above, I switched the accounts back to "Local Account" and the passwords are still remembered. i.e. switching back does not seem to reintroduce the bug.

I am guessing that the solution will also work if your starting position is with Windows accounts already setup to sign in with Microsoft account. i.e. switching to sign in with Local Accounts and then back to Microsoft account should hopefully fix it for you.

[image: Settings -> Accounts -> Your Info]

*An alternative solution that some are suggesting is to create a totally new Windows account and profile ... but the above "fix" is much easier and better IMHO.*

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue before, and disabling the task with these specific security options set will solve the problem. Please check if [this workaround](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9e053e78-fa99-47a9-b4ea-95b23e5aad5f/outlook-2019-randomly-shows-empty-account-passwords-for-all-email-accounts-after-upgrading-windows?forum=outlook) is suitable to you.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this did not help me. The passwords are still not remembered between restarts.

Answer (score 0):

For others with similar Outlook forgetting password issues, if @Tech-On-the_Beach's method does not solve your issue, please also see this [recent Microsoft support post "Outlook and other apps won't remember password after Windows Updates" Nov 6, 2020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-and-other-apps-won-t-remember-password-after-windows-updates-1e5a8a80-7112-440a-a18c-be2e50047a75) regarding widespread problem with Windows 10 forgetting passwords held for some applications after update to Win 10 version 2004. The article has detailed instructions for a workaround that sounds similar to @Jeff Yang7's reference above to disabling certain Task Scheduler Tasks.